# Why do we need to create a table first and then pass it as argument for pie plot in R?

Tags: r, data-visualization, pie-chart

Here is my piece of code:

```
myTable <- table(mtcars$am)  
pie(myTable)
```

Comment: You don't, you just have to supply 'a vector of non-negative numerical quantities' (from the help page). But it is up to you to ensure that those numerical quantities represent what you want to be plotted.

PS, pie charts are generally considered to be a very bad thing. I would consider using a bar chart instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the help `?pie` you have

> x: a vector of non-negative numerical quantities.  The values in
>             ‘x’ are displayed as the areas of pie slices.
>
> labels: one or more expressions or character strings giving names for
>             the slices.  Other objects are coerced by ‘as.graphicsAnnot’.
>             For empty or ‘NA’ (after coercion to character) labels, no
>             label nor pointing line is drawn.

So you don't need to pass a table but a `vector of non-negvative values` unless you want as in your case to summarize the data.

`table(mtcars$am)` returns a 2x2 table of the count of the two labels (0 & 1 here):

```
>> table(mtcars$am)

   0  1 
   19 13 

>> mtcars$am

   1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

[image: pie with table]
[image: pie without table]

A table, or better a data frame, is often a handy way of dealing with data to have all the data relating to a certain type or topic you're working on from being all over the place in the form of variables. This is especially handy when you're dealing with several datasets.

Answer (score 0):

`table` (cross) tabulates data into something understandable by `pie`.

Indeed, (see `?pie`), `pie` needs `x:   a vector of non-negative numerical quantities. The values in x are displayed as the areas of pie slices.`

If you don't use `table`, `pie` will plot as many (non <= 0) slices. You can read`?pie` for more details, and try the following: `pie(sample(1:5, 12, replace=T))` and also `example(pie)`.